# Finding "untagged" content in XML files using DocumentBuilder/Document in Java

Tags: java, xml, document

I have to parse a XML Document. I'm using javas DocumentBuilder class to create a document. The structure of the xml file looks like this:

```
<text>
    <something>
        <word>
            Someword
        </word>
    </something>
    <something>
        <word>
            Someotherword
        </word>
    </something>
    .
    <something>
        <word>
            Someword
        </word>
    </something>
</text>
```

I need to extract the text. I started with extracting the words like this:

```
    final NodeList nl = dom.getElementsByTagName("word");
```

... and iterate over the given list, to reconstruct the text. The problems are the ".". I can't reconstruct the sentence structure with my approach. Is there an elegant way, to do this? How can I access the "."?

Comment: Why dont you put the "." in a tag like <something><dot></dot></something> and access it the same way you are accessing the rest..??

Comment: I have file with like 80k words. What makes it even worse is, that there are some metainformations which contain a dot. Because of that I can't simply make %s/\./<anything>\.<\/anything>/g

Comment: Well the way you have it is like the "." are text of the tag <text>. You could use getTextTrim() but that will return all the text inside the <text> element.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new tag in your xml file:

```
<fullstop />
```

You may want to view this [document](http://www.d.umn.edu/cs/thesis/nachiket_kamat_ms.pdf), but how trustful it is, I can't say.

And, it's not too late to re-desing or re-structure your document. to avoid such issues later.

Comment: I have file with like 80k words. What makes it even worse is, that there are some metainformations which contain a dot. Because of that I can't simply make %s/\./<anything>\.<\/anything>/g

Comment: what to you mean by: `%s/\./<anything>\.<\/anything>/g` ?

Comment: This is the vim command for substitude a dot by <anything>.</anything>